# python module import fails when using pm2

Tags: python, python-module, pm2

I try to run a python3 script notifying be about twitter posts on my Ubuntu server. Doing this in command line works fine, but when I use pm2 to keep the script online after closing the console, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/root/projects/Twitterbot/main.py", line 1, in <module>
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
ImportError: No module named tweepy.streaming
```

When I switch the interpreter from `python` to `python3` nothing at all happens, it doesn't crash. It takes some RAM, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Does someone know what might be the issue? An other Python script (which imports a lot of things) is running fine without any issues.

I already reinstalled tweepy using pip but no change

Comment: Did you install tweepy for python 2?

Comment: maybe something to do with your python path

Comment: and did you import tweepy and/or tweepy.Stream?

Comment: @CaryShindell I simply ran `pip install tweepy`
@arodjabel How can I find out if this is the issue

Comment: Hold on, you said your script is in python3??

Comment: Yes it is. Here's the source I used in case it helps https://github.com/NNTin/discord-twitter-bot

Comment: @CaryShindell Forgot to tag you in the previous message.

Answer (score 6):

`but it doesn't seem to do anything`

I had a similar problem, it turns out `python3` buffers all output by default with `pm2` or `nohup`. So the logs won't show anything and `pm2 monit` won't show anything.

Run `python3` with `-u` flag to flush everything ASAP.

`pm2 start myscript.py --interpreter python3 --interpreter-args -u`

Comment: I'm not sure if the bot even started. I'm building my own one with nodejs now, too bad in python ;)